# $\zeta(1 + 2/x)$ has a strange, nearly linear behaviour

Tags: analysis, riemann-zeta, linear-approximation

I was messing around with some infinite sums in $\ell^p$ spaces and I encountered a strange result:

[image: zeta(1 + 2/x) looks very linear]

$\zeta\left(1 + \frac{2}{x}\right)$ looks like it is linear in $x$ for $x > 1$! A simple linear regression gives me $\zeta\left(1 + \frac{2}{x}\right)\approx 0.593413 + 0.499801 x$. The greatest difference appears to be relatively small. [image: an attempt to determine the error]

Is this true? If so, how could I show this? And if not, why does it appear to be nearly linear?

Comment: Check its series expansion [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+%CE%B6%281%2B2%2Fx%29). For $x \rightarrow \infty$ you have a line with slope $1/2$ and the Euler-Mascheroni constant as independent term.

Comment: I'm familiar with the series expansion of zeta but at least to me it's not intuitive that all but the linear order term are vanishing in that expansion (or something else I'm not aware of is going on)

Comment: The terms with negative powers of $x$ will vanish. Just take the limit of $1/x^n$ with a positive value of $n$ and take $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, NoOne!

Comment: We would see the same behavior for any function with a simple pole at $z=1$.

Comment: $100$ is a small number. Try plotting on $[1,10000]$.

Comment: @GregMartin that's a very good point, I actually didn't know that zeta has a simple pole at $z = 1$ but that does make a lot more sense